# Are broker nodes in kafka cluster configured to handle number of partition?

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka places the partitions and replicas in a way that the brokers with least number of existing partitions are used first. Does it mean that brokers are pre-configured to handle the partitions.

Comment: Yes, Brokers are responsible for handling partitions but you can also override its behavior as per your need. I'm not very much clear with your question, could you please add some more information.

Comment: Are brokers pre configured to have slots where in partitions reside? Say a broker has 5 slots and hence can only occupy 5 partitions.

Comment: There is nothing like this.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a topic, you set the number of partitions.

```
 bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

Also, there is a `num.partions` parameter you can use. (This is used when a topic is automatically created.)

A broker can have as many partitions as it wants as long as it has enough diskspace, memory, and network bandwidth.

[image]

In the screenshot above, you can see the partition of `test`.  If you make a topic with three partitions, you will have two more folders with `test-1` and `test-2`.

[image]

Each partition has an index file, a timeindex file, and a log file. The log file keeps Kafka data for that partition.